# To sleep in C, should I use while with a clock, or a system call?

Tags: c, sleep, system-calls

I was checking out [clock() on cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/clock/). Their example involves making the process wait for a second and then output a line, in a loop until 10 seconds have ellapsed. I need to do something similar in the homework assignment I'm working on. What I was wondering was this: if I just send my program into a loop, isn't that using system resources to just spin me around? In this case, wouldn't a system call be better?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your first sentence reveals your biggest mistake. :-)

Comment: Instead of cplusplus.com use [POSIX.1-2008 reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, using a system call or library function like `sleep()` is much better.  That `clock()` example is just meant to just show how to correctly call the function and interpret its return value, not to illustrate the best way to make a program wait.

Comment: That's what I thought. So I'm doing system("sleep 2") for instance. This is all cool?

Comment: Ah, don't do that. Don't start up a whole shell just to sleep for two seconds.

Comment: @Ziggy, no, that's worse.  There's a `sleep(unsigned int seconds)` function defined in `<unistd.h>` on any Unix/Linux system.  On Windows, there's `Sleep(DWORD dwMilliseconds)`.

Comment: **Never** use `system`. At best it's massively wasteful of resources, and at worst (and usually) it introduces major dangerous bugs into your program.

Comment: Yes, but just for information, how is clock() value calculated in this case ?

Answer (score 4):

That is a weird-ass example. I know it's just an example but ...

To sleep, call `sleep(unsigned int)`.

There are other calls (`nanosleep` on unix-y machines) for sub-second sleeps. And you can always use `select()` if you're old school.

Note that all of these can be interrupted so you may need to loop if for some reason they return early.

Comment: What header file are you including to get that sleep function? unistd.h?

Comment: Yup. On (most) unix-y machines, just do a `man 3 sleep` and it'll show you what you need to include.

Answer (score 2):

I have to add to the aforementioned that `sleep()` only puts the current thread to sleep, not the whole program, if it's multithreaded.

Comment: Nice point. There is nothing that will sleep all threads, is there?

Comment: Never heard of. Why would one want to spawn threads and make them all sleep at once? :) Such operation is only reasonable outside of the process, and there are various OS facilities (i.e. UNIX signals) serving that purpose.

Comment: If I squinch up my eyes really hard, I can come up with an implausible use case. I only asked because I'd never actually thought of it before reading your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear, you should NOT do something like the example.  If you do, your program will consume 100% of the CPU on one of the cores while it is waiting.  It is much better to use something like `sleep` or `select`.

Answer (score 0):

If your programme is multithreaded then better you go with `sleep()`.The reason is `clock()` will need extra coding for that while by using `sleep()` you can do your task with less memory and less time... `clock()` will involve CPU a lot...